# Inverter with active load

Tags: inverter

I'm studying the inverter with active load, whose circuit is the following:

[image]

The circuit is simple: the current mirror fixes the source to gate voltage of the PMOS, thus the plot of the drain current of M2 as a function of the source to drain voltage of M2 is univocally defined.
If vin increases from 0, we will get all the possible curves of the drain current of M1 as a function of the drain to source voltage of M1, each depending on the particular value of the gate to source voltage (i.e. vin) of M1.
The intersection of the characteristic of M2 with a characteristic of M1 gives the operating point, as illustrated in the following picture:

[image]

In the previous picture, the drain current of M1 (and M2) **is a function of the drain to source voltage of M1**.

**Question: how does the author of my book represent the PMOS characteristic (in which the current is a function of the source to drain voltage of the PMOS) in the same plot of the characteristics of the NMOS (in which the independent variable is the drain to source voltage of the NMOS)?**

Thank you